# Transform a numeric column into character

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I configured a csv import function to display a graph. After the import I choose the column defining my X, my Y and my Groupby. According to the CSV that I import, the ID field can be either numeric or in character. With this function, the displayed graph is correct when I import a CSV containing an ID in character, but not when it contains a numeric ID.

**It gives me this:**
[image]

---

**And I would like something like this :**
[image]

**Here is my code :**

```
  #-------- REACTIVE DATA --------#
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$csv_chart)
    infile <- input$csv_chart
    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read_csv(infile$datapath)
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'X', label = 'Field X:',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[1])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'Y', label = 'Field Y:',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[2])
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'group', label = 'Group by:',
                      choices = names(df), selected = names(df)[3])
    return(df)
  })


  #-------- PLOT CHART --------#
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data()) +
      geom_line(mapping = aes_string(x = input$X, y = input$Y, color= input$group)) +
      labs(x = input$X, y = input$Y, title = "Index Values")
  })
```

**What I tried is add a "as.character" in my ggplot function, but it changes nothing :**

```
geom_line(mapping = aes_string(x = input$X, y = input$Y, color= as.character(input$group))) +
```

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible so others can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the `ggplot` command with `aes` instead of `aes_string` should do the trick.

```
ggplot(data()) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = get(input$X), y = get(input$Y), color = as.character(get(input$group))))
```

The reason is: in `aes_string` you call `input$group` which is nothing but a character string. `as.character()` makes no sense here, since it turns the character string of the variable name into a character string.

With `aes` however, you can access the actual data behind the variable names using `get()`. On this data you can then use `as.character()` to turn it into a character string.